# OnDoubleTap is not working for TabHost

Tags: java, android, listener

I've a problem to use the touch listener for a TabHost. I want to handle the double-tap event for all views, so I decided to add the listener to the root view (in my case the TabHost).
In onCreate of my activity I setup the view as follows:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup();
tabHost.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
  private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(TestActivity.this,
    new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
      Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, "Hello World!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return true;
    }
  });

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
});

TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec(TAG_FIRST_TAB);
tab1.setContent(R.id.first_tab);
...
```

The app is built without any errors but if I start it and double-tap anywhere on the screen nothing happens.

Maybe it would also be helpful to see my tabhost layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            // several views for the tabs

        </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```